# What does @ mean when setting up A Records in your DNS settings?

Tags: dns

One of my domains wasn't working when I put https://example.com in my browser and it turned out to be because one of the A Records with "@" was pointing to the wrong spot. I was wondering what @ is for.

Comment: This information is easily available with a Google search. Have you done any research on this?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/83874/whats-the-meaning-of-in-a-dns-zone-file

Comment: Yes, I wasn't able to find it on Google.

Comment: @music2myear how can you search for special characters on google?

Comment: Google (in the browser, at least) natively translates symbols not part of their special query commands into % codes. Type "dns a record @ symbol" into Google and this is the query: https://www.google.com/search?q=dns+a+record+%40+symbol

Comment: And that is also where the answer was found.

Comment: Further, DNS is a decently well documented system, including the "@" symbol's use in it. So if you could not find a specific query that returned the results you needed, looking for DNS A Record documentation would have also given you your answer.

Comment: I just came here from a google search.  It would have been better if music2myear would have just not commented at all.

Answer (score 6):

Finally found it by searching a different forum here: http://forums.devshed.com/dns-36/mean-setting-dns-settings-636502.html. "The @ symbol refers to just the domain... Basically when no prefix is used, the @ symbol can be used".

Comment: Sorry (first-time user) that's done now. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: We all learn by doing. Welcome.